# iOS Predicate for CoreData with long long values were not precise enough

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, ios8.1, xcode6.1.1

This app I have been building runs on iPad and I have been testing it on iOS8.1 using XCode 6.1.1. I am having a problem where I try extract records by comparing the date of a record in milliseconds. The records are stored using CoreData.

The firstDate of a record is declared as follows

```
record.firstDate = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:1423288915464];
```

The firstDate is declared in the .h file of the record in this way:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * firstDate;
```

The predicate is declared this way:

```
NSNumber* prevStartMillis = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:1423324800000];
NSNumber* prevEndMillis = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:1423411199000];    

NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstDate >= %lld AND firstDate < %lld", [prevStartMillis longLongValue], prevEndMillis longLongValue]];
```

I did get some of the records with firstDate that falls within the specified range. However, I get a few records that do not fall within the specified range like these 3 of the many:

```
...
FirstDate:1423288915464
FirstDate:1423282909663
FirstDate:1423286413320
...
```

Previously I had a similar problem on another app for iPhone 6 iOS8.1 using XCode 6.1.1 as well. I was able to solve it by declaring the predicates with %lld for long long values. However, when I use the same code, it fails on iPad. Does anyone know what is it that I did wrong? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1: Workaround**
I have a workaround (though not very efficient). Here is the code snippet after I extract the records if anyone is wondering:

```
NSMutableArray* validRecords = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(Record* record in results) {
    if([record.firstDate longLongValue] >= [prevStartMillis longLongValue] && [record.firstDate longLongValue] <= [prevEndMillis longLongValue])
        [validRecords addObject:record];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to extract `long` from `NSNumber` like you do.
You can use NSNumber objects explicitly to create predicate

```
NSNumber* prevStartMillis = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:1423324800000];
NSNumber* prevEndMillis = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:1423411199000];    

NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstDate >= %@ AND firstDate < %@", prevStartMillis, prevEndMillis];
```

**EDITED:** 
I've reviewed your code again and figured out that numbers that you had wrote are out of your range. Just let's write your long numbers in shorter manner:

```
NSNumber* prevStartMillis = /*14233e+8*/;
NSNumber* prevEndMillis = /*14234e+8*/;
```

and this numbers are out of range:

```
...
FirstDate:14232e+8
FirstDate:14232e+8
FirstDate:14232e+8
...
```

So now it's easy to notice that this numbers are 'a bit' smaller to satisfy you condition

Comment: Thanks, it works as well but it still does not solve the problem I am having.

Comment: Hi, I tested your way it works for my case! However, this does not work if the predicate specified is down to the milliseconds e.g. between 1423324800004 to 1423324800006. Regardless, I don't think I will be checking records to that kind of precision so I am going to mark yours as the correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its signed and unsigned value problem.
You can use %llu and check if it works.

Comment: Hi, i tried and it's still the same. I gave up and used a if statement

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to have a if statement to check the dates after I retrieve the records (refer to Edit 1 in the question)